# What do these U-boot arguments do?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am looking at a [uEnv.txt](https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/board/beaglebone/uEnv.txt) file with the following lines:

```
bootpart=0:1                                                                                                                               
devtype=mmc
bootdir=                                                                                                                                   
bootfile=zImage                                                                                                                            
bootpartition=mmcblk0p2                                                                                                                    
set_mmc1=if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv bootpartition mmcblk1p2; fi                                                           
set_bootargs=setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/${bootpartition} rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait                                 
uenvcmd=run set_mmc1; run set_bootargs;run loadimage;run loadfdt;printenv bootargs;bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
```

Some of these things make sense. For example, line 7 sets the u-boot environment variable `bootargs` (documented [here](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootEnvVariables)) with kernel command-line parameters (documented [here)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).

On line 5, `bootpartition` is set which is later used in the kernel arguments.

However, many of the variables never seem to be used anywhere (i.e. `bootpart`, `devtype`, `bootfile`, etc). What are these for and where can I find documentation? Also, why does the `setenv bootargs...` line need to be assigned to `set_bootargs`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot look at a uEnv.txt file by itself, you need to look at in the context of the board's environment as a uEnv.txt will be loaded to modify the existing environment and also run that uenvcmd.  It's quite likely those variables you don't see directly referenced are referenced in other parts of the full environment such as loadimage.

Comment: I guess I'm not familiar with loadimage. Where can I find more information on that?

Comment: If you interrupt the boot process (hitting space for example) and printenv you will see all of the various environment variables and loadimage is in there.

Comment: Where do those environment variables come from? Are they compiled into u-boot?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the default for that particular config.

Comment: I found a file called include/configs/am335x_evm.h in the u-boot build directory. This file seemed to have a lot of these variables. Is this the config file that you are referring to?

Comment: I found a very helpful web page
https://nnc3.com/mags/LJ_1994-2014/LJ/246/11725.html